# Google Analytics in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been following this guide on how to implement Google Analytics in Ruby on Rails.

http://railsapps.github.io/rails-google-analytics.html

I followed the steps and created a JavaScript file named google_analytics.js.coffee in my app/assets/javacsripts directory.

Following the instructions, I replaced UA-XXXXXXX-XX with my Tracking ID.

In application.js, I also have //= require/tree

However when I add, commit and deploy and view the source code, I can't see the Google Analytics Source Code.

Was there something I missed? Was there something wrong with that article?

Comment: Do you see a file called google_analytics.js being included in the source code?

Comment: I'm removing the google-analytics tag since it's a ruby on rails question. But I just wanted to point out that the tutorial seems to use an old version of the google analytics tracking code. You should update it to use the new version that is documented here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/